# When using a websocket wrapper, how is data "framed"?

Tags: javascript, websocket, libwebsockets

I've been testing [Caddy Server](https://caddyserver.com/) and [Web Socket Daemon](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) to see how easy it is to support WebSockets from a server environment. Both of these solutions are abstractions that use standard input/output from a command line program of your choosing (written in any language of your choosing).

However, both programs are line-based. That is, if your command line program writes a single "message" to standard output that contains a newline character, your JavaScript websocket code will see two distinct messages.

**Is there any way to avoid this problem?**

*EDIT:* As an unofficial answer, you can perform multiple encodings to avoid the newline issue. For example, if your command line program is responding with JSON-encoded data, you can simply base64 encode the data before writing it to standard output. The JavaScript would then call `atob()` on this data before JSON-decoding it. Using multiple encodings adds a slight size overhead but it does avoid issues with the newline character (and potentially any other issues with other non-printing and control characters).

Comment: Did you tried using a \ before entering new line ?

Comment: Just did then. It does not work.